# Twitter request from Parse Cloud Code fails with "Could not authenticate you."

Tags: javascript, android, twitter, parse-platform, oauth

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

This is what I get when trying to perform a [GET users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) request to Twitter. Some background:

- User is authenthicated in my Android app through `ParseTwitterUtils`;
- From Android, I call a parse.com Cloud Code function passing in the user token and token secret (looks like bad practice, but for now I'd just like to see this work);
- From Cloud Code, I format the auth header using [this github library](https://github.com/sreejithbnaick/Twitter-OAuth-1.1-Signature-Generator-js). This is needed as explained [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests).

You can see some of my code below. Android launch code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("twitterId", ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().getUserId());
params.put("authToken", ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().getAuthToken());
params.put("authTokenSecret", ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().getAuthTokenSecret());
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("fetchPictureFromTwitter", params, ... );
```

Cloud code main function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("fetchPictureFromTwitter", function(request, response) {

  var twitterId = request.params.twitterId;
  var authToken = request.params.authToken;
  var authTokenSecret = request.params.authTokenSecret;
  var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json";

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: url,
    followRedirects: true,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": getOAuthSignature(url,authToken,authTokenSecret)
    },
    params: {
      user_id: twitterId
    }

  }).then(...)
```

And lastly here's getOAuthSignature, the function used to sign the request (I took this from the example page in the github link):

```
var getOAuthSignature = function(url, authToken, authTokenSecret) {

    var nonce = OAuth.nonce(32);
    var ts = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var timestamp = ts.toString();

    var consumerKey = <MY-APP-CONSUMER-KEY>
    var consumerSecret = <MY-APP-CONSUMER-SECRET>

    var accessor = {
        "consumerSecret": consumerSecret,
        "tokenSecret": authTokenSecret
    };

    var params = {
        "oauth_version": "1.0",
        "oauth_consumer_key": consumerKey,
        "oauth_token": authToken,
        "oauth_timestamp": timestamp,
        "oauth_nonce": nonce,
        "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1"
    };

    var message = {
        "method": "GET",
        "action": url,
        "parameters": params
    };

    OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
    var normPar = OAuth.SignatureMethod.normalizeParameters(message.parameters);
    var baseString = OAuth.SignatureMethod.getBaseString(message);
    var sig = OAuth.getParameter(message.parameters, "oauth_signature") + "=";
    var encodedSig = OAuth.percentEncode(sig);

    return 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'+consumerKey+'", oauth_nonce=' + nonce + ', oauth_signature=' + encodedSig + ', oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp=' + timestamp + ',oauth_token="'+authToken+'", oauth_version="1.0"'
};
```

What could be wrong? I've spent two days on the matter now and I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that `user_id="<user-id>` has to be encoded in the request header as well as all the other `oauth_*` parameters. So I had to change this section:

```
var params = {
    "user_id": twitterId, // <- add here
    "oauth_version": "1.0",
    "oauth_consumer_key": consumerKey,
    "oauth_token": authToken,
    "oauth_timestamp": timestamp,
    "oauth_nonce": nonce,
    "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1"
};
```

And I'm passing the userId from the outer function, like `getOAuthSignature(url,twitterId,authToken,authTokenSecret)`.

As for passing auth token data from device to cloud, this is probably not needed because you can find all the authentication info in the `authData` field of any `ParseUser` (as long as it is linked with twitter or Facebook).